# improving computationnal speed of a kalman filter in Matlab

Tags: c, matlab, mex, kalman-filter

I am computing a statistical model in Matlab which has to run about 200 kalman filter per iteration, and I want to iterate the modelat least 10 000 times which suggest that I should run it at least 2 000 000 times. I am therefore searching for a way to optimize the computationnal speed of Matlab on this part. I have already gone operation per operation to try to optimize the computation in Matlab using all the tricks which could be used but I would like to go further...

I am not familiar with C/C++ but I read that mex-file could be usefull in some cases. Anyone could tell me if it would be Worth going into this direction ???
Thanks...

Comment: Using mex files *can* be faster, but only if you know how to write good C code. A lot of times optimizing m-files is far easier and faster (implementation and run time). Post your m-code and you may get helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

Writing mex files will definitely speed up the entire process, but you will not be able to use a lot of the built in MATLAB functions. You are limited to what you can do in C++ and C. Of course you can write your own functions, as long as you know how to.

The speed increase mainly comes from the fact the mex files are compiled and not interpreted line by line as are standard MATLAB scripts. Once you compile the mex you can call it the same way you do any other MATLAB function.

For a class I took in college I had to write my own image scaling function, I had initially written it in a standard script and it would take a couple seconds to complete on large images, but when I wrote it in C in a mex it would complete in less than 0.1 seconds.

[MEX Files Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/create-mex-files.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you you are not familiar at all with C/C++ this will be hard going. Hopefully you have some experience with another language besides Matlab? You can try learning/copying from the many [included examples](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/table-of-mex-examples.html), but you'll really need to figure out the basics first.

One thing in particular. If you use mex you'll need some way to obtain decent random numbers for your Kalman filter noise. You might be surprised, but a very large percentage of your calculation time will likely be in generating random numbers for noise (depending on the complexity of your filter it could be > 50%).

*Don't use the default random number generators in C/C++.*

These are not suitable for scientific computation, especially when generating vast numbers of values as you seem to need. Your first option is to pass in a large array of random numbers generated via `randn` in Matlab to your mex code. Or look into including the C code [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) algorithm itself and find/implement a scheme for generating normal random numbers from the uniform ones ([log-polar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method) is simplest, but [Ziggurat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm) will be faster). This is not too hard. I've done it myself and the [Double precision SIMD-oriented Fast Mersenne Twister (dSFMT)](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/SFMT/index.html#dSFMT) is actually 2+ times faster than Matlab's current implementation for uniform variates.

Answer (score 0):

You could use parfor loops or the parallel computing toolbox in general to speedup your calculations. Did you already checked whether MATLAB is using 100% CPU?